# Subsonic alias query - how?

Tags: subsonic, alias

I am trying to build the following query:

```
`new Select("GTekst = ArrGruppe.Tekst", "GLTekst = ArrGruppeLinie.Tekst")
.From(ArrGruppeLinie.Schema)
.InnerJoin(ArrGruppe.IdColumn, ArrGruppeLinie.ArrGruppeIDColumn)
.Where(ArrDeltager.Columns.Kategori).IsLessThan(20)
.And("Arrgruppe.Tekst").Like("mytext");`
```

It generates a flawed query because of the .And() because I have aliases attached on the two columns with the same name - the And-operator is here:

```
... AND (ArrGruppe.Tekst LIKE @ArrGruppe.Tekst1
)',N'@Kategori0 tinyint,@ArrGruppe.Tekst1 varchar(10)',@Kategori0=20,@ArrGruppe.Tekst1='mytext'
```

I haven't been able to find anything on Google which could solve this problem. How do I write the Subsonic query to generate a valid SQL parameter for ArrGruppe.Tekst ??

EDIT: Problem was solved with an update from 2.1 Final to version 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Select("GTekst = ArrGruppe.Tekst", "GLTekst = ArrGruppeLinie.Tekst")
  .From(ArrGruppeLinie.Schema)
  .InnerJoin(ArrGruppe.Columns.Id, ArrGruppeLinie.Columns.ArrGruppeID)
  .Where(ArrDeltager.Columns.Kategori).IsLessThan(20)
  .And(Arrgruppe.Columns.Tekst).Like("mytext");
```

If not try upgrading to the latest version of SubSonic http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/downloads/list because you may be hitting the following issue (fixed in 2.2)

Google Issue 31 - Where Expression not formatting correctly with qualified column name

Comment: I have a situation where I have two tables with matching column names "ArrGruppe.Tekst" and "ArrGruppeLinie.Tekst" that is. The question is: How to write a SubSonic query in which I generate aliases for the column names to make some valid SQL - and in the same query create an AND-filter based on one of the columns I've just created an alias for?

I tried your approach - the above generates the following:  

AND Tekst LIKE @Tekst1

...which is invalid because Tekst is an ambiguous column because there are two of them.

Please write again if you need further information  :o)

Comment: I've edited the query above so it should fix the ambiguous column name error. Let me know if it doesn't

Comment: Sorry. It generates the following AND-clause:

...AND ArrGruppe.Tekst LIKE @ArrGruppe.Tekst1

which is invalid because you can't have a dot in the parameter name.

Comment: That is very strange, which version of SubSonic are you using?

Comment: 2.1 Final... Should I file a bug report on subsonicproject.com?

Comment: Try 2.2 and see if you get the same problem. 

http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/downloads/list

Comment: Works like a charm - I can see in the release notes that there has been an issue with aliases on WHERE so I suppose it has been fixed between 2.1 and 2.2.

Thanks for helping me out on this one - I really appreciate it  :o)